# BCP import all files from a folder to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

BCP Import

How to do BCP import with all files in a folder.

***folder***

- file1.csv
- file2.csv

Need to import both the files.

```
bcp <tableName> in <filename> -t "^" -r "\n" -c -C 28591 -S <databaseinstance>  -U <username> -P <password>
```

Using the above BCP cmd, we can import only one file at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple BCP command import only single file.
To achieve the above we need to use looping with the command.

I have used the following command  simple command.

```
for /r %i in (*) do bcp <tablename> in  %i -t "^" -r "\n" -c -C 28591 -S <databaseinstance>  -U <username> -P <password>
```

It works.