# How to prevent null values to be inserted into the database table?

Tags: sql-server

I am inserting the file paths from local folder to my database table using `MASTER.DBO.XP_CMDSHELL`. all the paths are inserted into table including `null` at last. I want to prevent this `null` to be inserted into Filepath table.

I set the column as `not null` but it doesn't work as it aborted all the insert operations.

Here is my code:

```
declare @date varchar(20)= '2019/04/17'
declare @query varchar(max)
DECLARE @DD VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @MM VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @YYYY VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @PATTERN VARCHAR(50)
SET @PATTERN='*.CSV'
SET @DD=SUBSTRING(@DATE,9,2)
SET @MM=SUBSTRING(@DATE,6,2)
SET @YYYY=SUBSTRING(@DATE,1,4)
create table #z(id int identity(1,1),filepath varchar(max))
SET @QUERY ='MASTER.DBO.XP_CMDSHELL ''DIR D:\FILE\folder\'+@YYYY+'\'+@MM+'\'+@DD+'\'+@PATTERN +' /B/S'''
INSERT #z EXEC (@QUERY)
```

Comment: Make the field non-nullable. Why are you using `xp_cmdshell` though? If you want to execute a shell script, just do so from the shell. Open a command prompt and run the script. Or create a shell job in SQL Server Agent.

Comment: If you don't want `NULL` to be inserted, and you don't want the `INSERT` to fail if `NULL` is supplied what *do* you want to happen? If `NULL` is supplied as a value then the `DEFAULT` value won't be used either; you either need to omit the column from the `INSERT` statement or use the `VALUES` clause and use the `DEFAULT` operator.

Comment: `but it doesn't work as it aborted all the insert operations.` that's what you asked in this question. It did work. BTW why would any script that enumerates folders return null? You should post your code so people can help

Comment: I want to Insert all the paths except null

Comment: @PuranKandpal that doesn't explain anything. There are no null paths. Why did your code produce nulls? And why did you use `xp_cmdshell` at all? The problem is in that code - it's executed in the wrong way and returns the wrong data. Post the code so people can help

Comment: please check the updated code

Comment: Why do you use `xp_cmdshell` for this in the first place? That's like killing a fly with a cannon *and* requires elevated permissions. No DBA is going to enable `xp_cmdshell` just for this.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyway? Import some CSV files? You could use a tool like SSIS to import all files in a folder, including nested folders. You can also specify the folder path to read programmatically. It's far more robust and doesn't require weakening security

Comment: Or you could write a shell script that imported every file that matched a patter using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017), as shown in this question: [BCP import all files from a folder to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918127/bcp-import-all-files-from-a-folder-to-database). BCP offers options that aren't available when using `BULK INSERT` or `OPENROWSET`

Comment: can someone please help me in my code?

Comment: I'd just stick in a `DELETE #z WHERE filepath IS NULL` to get rid of it (or a `WHERE filepath IS NOT NULL` in a follow-up query). That's assuming I'd use `xp_cmdshell` at all, which I would not be inclined to do; this kind of logic is best handled outside T-SQL.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `DELETE #z WHERE filepath IS NULL` this is what i was doing but i want to know if any other possible solution for the same?

Comment: If you insist on keeping `xp_cmdshell`, then no. That's because `dir` will always end with a blank line and `xp_cmdshell` will always translate that into `NULL`. "Fixing" that could be probably be done with arcane magic in a `.cmd` file, but if you're willing to go that far you should also be willing to abandon `xp_cmdshell` altogether.